# SAP HANA XS and SAPUI5 Membership and Role Provider

Tags: sapui5, hana-xs

I am a newbie for SAP, I am using SAP HANA Studio. Have projects of SAPUI5 (MVC) & SAP HANA XS. On my researches I couldn't find an satisfying answer. Is there and if yes, What are the ways to use Membership and Role provider in SAPUI5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe try to elaborate more on what your scenario / use-case is? I don't seem to be able to fully understand what you are trying to ask. SAP UI5 is just a bunch of UI libraries that is specific to SAP applications. There shouldn't be any membership / role involvement in developing a UI5 application since the admin should be the one doing that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no membership / role provider in UI 5. But HANA XS uses database users and you can create and assigns roles to them (to access certain database tables/views, execute procedures). You can also specify if users have to be authenticated to access your application using an .xsaccess file (http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/5f/e3b123826d4503aa66eb955a002821/content.htm?fullscreen=true)